# Flex binding not working

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I'am having problems with, binding variables being updated. I've made custom TitleWindow component which have text-input and check-box control. When the check-box changes its value, the XML in parent application should also, but it doesn't nor does the

> warning: unable to bind to property

Here is the code:

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XMLList id="nastavitve">
            <nastavitve>
                <zacetek omogocen="{p_zacet.selected}">
                    <slika>{slika_i.text}</slika>
                    <opis>{opis_i.text}</opis>
                </zacetek>
                <konec omogocen="{p_konc.selected}">
                    <tockovanje>{tock.selected}</tockovanje>
                    <kljuc>{kljuc.text}</kljuc>
                    <besedilo>{besedilo.text}</besedilo>
                </konec>
            </nastavitve>   
        </fx:XMLList>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Binding source="nastavitve" destination="parentApplication.XML_KODA.nastavitve" />
```

Main application:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="XML_KODA" format="e4x" >
        <shramba>
            <nastavitve/>
            <elementi/>
        </shramba>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Bindable] property in the parent control.
Usually flex compiler will give 'Unable to bind to property' warning when the [Bindable] tag is not there.

If you are not using Bindable tag the binding may not happen correctly. We can't predict the binding process if that tag is missing. sometimes it will get bound, sometimes not.
so first check whether the bindable tag is there or not

Comment: Yes I have [Bindable]. On the end I gave up and used Events. Thanks for help!